# What does if-else code do?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, if-else

I just started a new job and in one of the procedures I was given for one of my tasks I found this piece of code. It just adds a comment to a field that's already filled up. For instance, field1 might have an ABC001 code, and in the final stage we need it to show as 'Feature not found: ABC001'

```
'Comment ' + (!field1! if !field1! else '')
```

`'Comment' + !field1!` works as well. I don't understand what the condition in the first piece of code does.

Comment: Apparently, the condition is just telling explicitly to not show anything in case the field value is empty.

Comment: `'Comment ' + !field1!` may cause error if value of field1 is None. If it is None then the empty string '' is used

Answer (score 2):

What the `!field1! if !field1! else ''` expression does is evaluate if the corresponding value of !field1! exists or not. If there is a value, then it keeps that value and adds it to `'Comment'`. However, if there is no value (it evaluates to `None`) it will keep and empty string (`''`).

Here is an illustrative example:

Suppose the value of `field1` is 'ABC001' for the first row. Run the folowings lines in a Python console:

```
value = 'ABC001'
print(value if value else '')
# It will print ABC001
```

This way, the resulting value for the new field will be `Comment ABC001` in the first row. On the other hand, consider that the value of `field1` is empty (`None`) in the second row. Now try to run these lines:

```
value = None  # this is not a string but rather a Python object
print(value if value else '')
# It will print nothing as '' it is an empty string
```

Therefore, the value of `field1` in the second row will be just `Comment`.

You could change the condition and play around with different values. For example:

```
value = None  # this is not a string but rather a Python object
print(value if value else 'new comment')
# It will print new comment
```